# MonoGame not working

Tags: c#, monogame

I am just getting started with MonoGame (and game programming in general) and cant run any programs. I keep getting this exception message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'openal32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a dll was not found!

Comment: If you read the error message, you'll see you are missing `openal32.dll`. Find it somewhere and put it with the other `dll`s.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to install OpenAL.

This is included in the standard MonoGame installer, and placed in  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\oalinst.exe"`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to install OpenAL. If you're bulding windows game project it will be wise to add OpenAL DLL file links into your project and mark them to be copied to Output directory. This way your deployed game will not require separate OpenAL installation on client (or even on another dev machine).

Dll files are:

```
OpenAL32.dll
wrap_oal.dll
```

Comment: In my case, OpenAL32.dll was already enough to get the project started.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when you have win10 it includes directX, so if you are using win 8 or less you need to install direct10: the link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35&nowin10

and.... finally works!!!